# How to Traverse A Square from Greatest Distance (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on a program where I need to traverse a square from greatest distance to shortest distance, when starting from the center and given a maximum range that the object can travel.

The traversal would look something like this, each step is labeled starting from 0 to 35 (sorry for crappy diagram). Max distance would be 3 from center:

[image: Square Traversal from Longest to Shortest Distance]

I was thinking it could work in two for loops, but I don't think that will work anymore without a ton of `if` statements. I want it to be semi-efficient if possible.

I don't need any code, just some ideas on how to get it to work (although feel free to post whatever).

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Just to get you started: At any time, you will be going in one of four directions.  Each direction has an `addToX` and `addToY` that tells you how much to add to each axis.  So for East, `addToX` is 1 and `addToY` is 0; for North, `addToX` is 0 and `addToY` is -1.  That should help you come up with code that works no matter what direction you're going.

Comment: Also, note the directions you traverse in (from left of 0): [E6,S5,W5,N4,E4,S3,W3,N2,E2,S1,W1]. There's a definite pattern there.

Comment: Oh, those are both great tips. That definitely helps too, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of would involve 5 loops - one for each direction (all separate loops), and then one for the distance from the outside (which would be the outer-most loop).

The outer-most loop's value would allow us to determine where each loop should start and end.

As a rough draft, I imagine it would look something like this:

```
for i = 0 to n
  for x = i to (n-i-1)
    // process matrix[x][i]

  for y = i to (n-i-1)
    // process matrix[n-i][y]

  for x = (n-i) downto i
    // process matrix[x][n-i]

  for y = (n-i) downto i
    // process matrix[i][y]
```

I'll leave it to you to write the actual code.

Comment: Hm, I stumbled upon something sort of like that. I was just wondering if there was a general solution people used, but my solution will probably be pretty similar to this.
Thanks!